# Loading page to page in Stimulsoft in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stimulsoft

I have a problem with stimulsoft in mvc. I really appreciate if anyone can help me and knows anything about this problem.
All of our information will send in stimulsoft as default way and in stimvcviewer all of the information will be display.

When we have lots of information, user should wait until information load completely because of that user could see some information that need. This process maybe boring for users.

I want a solution. I want after the first page loaded in stimvcviewer,  remain pages load with this component and add report to component (stimvcviewer) when every page loaded one by one. 
is anyone have any solution that can help me? Thank you

I have another question. have component this feature? if component(stimvcviewer) have this feature , how should we implement?

I have another question.how should we load item one to one in Time loading?
I have another question.how should we work json in Stimulsoft?

Comment: Please seperate into multiple questions if it makes sense (I do not really understand the content of your questions).

Comment: soulation load large data in stimulsoft mvc

http://forum.stimulsoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=5278